# how to syntax <pre> element in html document

Tags: html

I'm a beginner in HTML. I'm having problem in how to syntax my html doc. If I indent the second line inside the `<pre>` element, the pre formatted text doesn't appear correctly in the browser.

```
<body>
    <dl>
        <dt>thing 1</dt>
            <dd>Description text</dd>
            <dd><blockquote>
                <pre>Pre formated text first line.
                Pre formatted text second line</pre>
            </blockquote></dd>
    </dl>
</body>
```

[The result looks like this](http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh562/syllabear1995/Screen%20Shot%202016-12-02%20at%2011.20.25%20AM.png)

but if I want the text to appear correctly in the browser, my document becomes a mess.

```
<body>
    <dl>
            <dt>thing 1</dt>
                <dd>Description text</dd>
                <dd><blockquote>
                    <pre>Pre formated text first line.
Pre formatted text second line</pre>
                </blockquote></dd>
    </dl>
</body>
```

How to syntax the `<pre>` element correctly?

Comment: This is happening because you are also adding some spaces before <pre> tag. By doing that, the preformatted text starts after some indentation... The best way to do it is to start the <pre> tag at the begining of the line.

Comment: @wanjarisushil but then, the whole <pre> element will not be indented, and the doc will still be a mess.

Comment: Yes, but that's how it behaves. If you give some whitespaces before the text, all the whitespaces will appear on the browser output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<body>
<dl>
    <dt>thing 1</dt>
        <dd>Description text</dd>
        <dd><blockquote>
            <pre>
              Pre formated text first line.<br>
              Pre formatted text second line
            </pre>
        </blockquote></dd>
</dl>
```

Add CSS

```
pre {
white-space: normal;
```

}

Comment: Then it's no longer a <pre>, I can just use <p>.

Comment: No, <p> will wrap text even if you have content on two different lines unlike <pre>. The code I posted shows using <pre> tag while still maintaining the format of the document just the way you wanted. But the decision to use <p> or <pre> depends on the actual text you need to display. Here is a link about <pre> tag to understand its usage [link] (https://www.sitepoint.com/everything-need-know-html-pre-element/) such as showing <code> tag within or displaying conversation type text between people.